# PostgreSQL check if at least one item from array is in a string

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql

How to check if at least one item from array is in a string in PostgreSQL. For example:
I have a string '123456789' and an array ARRAY['a','b','1','c'] i need somehow to check in WHERE if at least one item from ARRAY is in string

return true if it is

return false if non of the items are in string.

In above example it has to return true, if the array was ARRAY['a','b','d','c'] then it must return false

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65823883/edit) the question as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the input string into an array using [string_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.16.1.1.1) with a "NULL" separator.

Then use the [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) operator `&&`

```
where string_to_array('12345678', null) &&  ARRAY['a','b','1','c']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
where string ~ array_to_string(ar, '|')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3aea570ce69e0e852c80819fe8a25ac2) is a db<>fiddle.

The advantage of this approach over converting the string to an array is that it works for longer strings -- it supports character-by-character comparisons.  It also supports longer comparisons.

One downside is that it doesn't work if the strings in `ar` include regular expression special characters.